# Printing data from Object/Hashmap by getters/keys

Tags: java, hashmap, printf

I have a object like this:

```
public class Person {
       String name = "Any";
       int    age  = 9001; 
}
public String getName() {return this.name;}
public int getAge()     {return this.age;}
```

Is there a way to print this data with predefined template as stated below?

```
Person firstOne = new Person();
print_throw_getters("Name: $name%s Age: $age%i",firstOne);
```

If no, I can convert an Object in the HashMap:

```
public HashMap getHashMap {
    HashMap test = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    test.put("name",this.getName());
    test.put("age",this.getAge());
    return test;
}
```

Is there a function to print values by keys in predefined template, like this?

```
print_throw_keys("Name: $name%s Age: $age%i",firstOne.getHashMap());
```

I do not want to use the indexes like printf("name: $1%s",string) since templates vary considerably, but the incoming object type is unique.
.

**UPD:** Thanks for the answers, but the idea is that there will be a file with a list of templates, which will be inserted into the data, for example:

```
String template1 = "Your selected Name is $name%s and selected age $age%i";
String template2 = "User: $name%s; Age: $age%i";
```

Accordingly, the objects themselves will contain a lot more getters.

Comment: Override `toString()`.

Comment: I believe you can return a formatted String from the overridden `toString()` method in your class !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
[MapFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/AtextformatsimilartoMessageFormatbutusingstringratherthannumerickeys.htm)

Example:

```
String text = "Your selected Name is {name} and selected age {age}";
HashMap test = new HashMap();
test.put("name", "Mr. X");
test.put("age", "21");
System.out.println("Example: " + MapFormat.format(text, test));
```

Output:

Example: Your selected Name is Mr. X and selected age 21

Comment: This is very similar to what I need, but I still would have preferred an option with getters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in the Java API that can do such a thing, but it is easily implemented:

```
public static String buildMessage(Map<String, Object> data, String template) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%([A-Za-z0-9_]+);");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(template);
    int offset = 0;
    while(m.find()) {
        int start = m.start(1) - 1 + offset;
        int end = m.end(1) + 1 + offset;
        String field = m.group(1);
        String value = data.get(field).toString();
        offset += -2 - field.length() + value.length();
        template = template.substring(0, start) + value + template.substring(end);
    }
    return template;
}
```

and then you can use such method as follows:

```
String template = "-- this is my name: %name;, and my age: %age; --";
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", "Robert Smith");
data.put("age", 20);
System.out.println(buildMessage(data, template));
```

This method is just a skeleton, if you want to use it for something more serious you'll have to improve this method to do the following:

- validate that field names have only A-Z, a-z, 0-9,  (or modify the regex)
- validate cases where the template has fields not specified in the map
- some other things that I'm missing right now

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the number of arguments and their order in the template in advance.

Comment: @Arkham.vm do you know the format of those templates? are you going to design such templates or is something already done?

Comment: I'm going to design it by myself, so that if the existing solutions with a different design template, this is acceptable.

Comment: I edited my answer, but I thing it would have been better if I added another answer

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try to finish the library linked by PraK.

Answer (score 0):

Just `override` the `toString()` method on your person `object.`

in person object

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "Name:"+this.name+"age:"+this.age;

    }
```

then use like `System.out.printLn(person.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Override  [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) function to print from object state.

Example:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: "+this.getName()+" Age: "+this.getAge()";

    }
```

and to use it:

```
Person p = new Person();
...
System.out.println(p);
```

Couple of examples:

[Ref1](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/09/override-tostring-method-java-tips-example-code.html)

[Ref2](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/08/overriding-the-tostring-method-in-object-class/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an application of the Template Method design Pattern ...